# how do i plot a sorted array in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have sorted all the turtles by the value of a property called point.
now I want a plot of point versus turtle number. how do I do this?

```
turtles-own [ point ]

 to setup
 ca
 crt 100
 reset-ticks
 end

 to go
 repeat 100[
 ask turtles[
  if random 10 = 1[
   set point  point + 1
  ]
 ]
 ];;sorting 

 let array sort-on [point] turtles
 tick
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "turtle number", I assume you mean the location in the list.  Then replace `let array sort-on [point] turtles` with `plotByOrder` where

```
to plotByOrder
  clear-plot
  let pts sort [point] of turtles
  foreach pts [[pt] -> plot pt]
end
```

Of course, you will need to have created a plot in the interface, and this assumes it is the current plot.